# Twitter bootstrap 2.3 pulls 3rd

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I didn't lock my bootstrap version, and did bundle update and it pulled 3 version. When I go and lock my gem to 2.3 and update it, still pulls version 3. Is it suppose to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Look inside Gemfile.lock. You probably need to edit it to match the older version of Bootstrap. I would usually just trash the Gemfile.lock and re-bundle, but that may update other gems to later versions if you don't have them specified in the Gemfile. If you ran `bundle update` and Bootstrap is the only thing that updated then you are probably OK just trashing gemfile.lock and re-bundling.